# printf differentiating between a character and a number

Tags: c

I'm trying to make an algorithm that takes command line input and divides [1] by [2] (given that [1] and [2] are numbers, and [2] is not 0) but

```
if ((atof(argv[2]) == 0))
```

accepts both letters and numbers for some reason.

My current code cannot differentiate between 0 and letters. How do I fix this? I only started coding a week ago so I'm sorry if my code is messy and thank you for anything you can say to help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])

{

if ((atof(argv[2]) == 0))

{

    printf("invalid input - divide by zero not allowed\n");
    return 0;

}

else if ((atof(argv[1])) && (atof(argv[2])))

{

    float sum = 0;

    sum = (atof(argv[1])) / (atof(argv[2]));

    printf("%f\n", sum);
    return 0;

}

else

    printf("invalid input\n");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "accepts" exactly? What do you want to happen if letters are input? What *precisely* do you want to do? If you want to read a line of input and then analyze it to see if it's a number, why not write code to do that?

Comment: Test for letters before you convert to numbers. What do you expect an ancient C-language function to return when the input is non numeric?

Comment: If you supply a letter to `atof`, it will return `0.000000`.

Comment: Research `strtod()`

Comment: If you input 2 4 I want it to output 0.5 .
If you input 1 0 I want it to output "invalid input - divide by zero not allowed".
If you input 2 a I want it to output "invalid input".

Comment: @WeatherVane I see, thank you! That explains a lot

Comment: @kfsone That makes sense, I'll try that now.

Comment: Is that C or C++? They ae different languages, pick the tag for the language you use!

Comment: @Olaf I changed it to C, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) to tell whether a character is a digit (you still have to convert it to the digit's value later).

But what you really want is to use [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)/[`strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) ([`atof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atof) has no way to tell you it failed) and not worry about manual string to digit conversion.

```
float numerator, denominator;
bool success = sscanf(argv[1], "%f", &numerator) == 1;
success = success && (sscanf(argv[2], "%f", &denominator) == 1);
if(success && denominator != 0) { // float to value comparison is almost always a bad idea
    printf("Fraction: %f\n", numerator/denominator);
} else {
    printf("Failure\n");
}
```

Comment: I modified it a bit, since I don't need to check if the numerator is a 0.

Answer (score 1):

you should use strtof function instead of atof

```
float strtof(const char *nptr, char **endptr);
```

nptr is the pointer to the string you want to interpret as a float.
endptr has to be the address of a char pointer (that's why it has double star, it's a pointer to a char pointer).

the function stores the address of the first character past the last character interpreted in the char pointer pointed by endptr.

If no conversion is performed, zero is returned and the value of nptr is stored in the location referenced by endptr.

Comment: Please can you expand the answer for the beginner as to how a double star function argument is used?